# How to change: 2018-01-03 21:00:00 to 3 January 21:00 with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

What should I do with  2018-01-03 21:00:00 to get 3 January 21:00(without year)

Comment: `"2018-01-03 21:00:00".substr(11, 5);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the date pipe: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

```
{{yourDate | date: 'dd MMMM HH:mm'}}
```

Example with your API:

```
http.get(url).then(function(res) {
  $scope.data = res.list;

  angular.forEach($scope.data, function(item) {
    item.dt_txt = new Date(item.dt_txt);
  });
});
```

Comment: I know about this,but my date include " - ",maybe this fact crashs angularjs,because I can't use your syntax,just try by yourself

Comment: Ok,that's good ,but can u help me to rewrite this not to static variable.I mean,i get strings from API and need to convert all of them and don't write everyone to variable on Js

Comment: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=london&units=metric&cnt=5&appid=338d293879598530ec8cef82c5d375d4 this. And use ng-repeat

Comment: Thx,i'm beginer and have some problems with it.Here my cut of code,if u can write ur resolving  https://codepen.io/mikepavlyuk/pen/eyVjPo